# Lucene Purposely Corrupt Index For Unit Test

Tags: unit-testing, junit, lucene

I have some code that deletes and rebuilds a Lucene index if it is caught as corrupt and I would like to unit test this functionality. What is the best way to purposely corrupt a test FSDirectory and then perform unit tests on the corrupted index?

I am assuming only the File System directory can be corrupted, but if there is a way to simulate the same thing with the RAM Directory that would be even better as I prefer to use the RAM in my lucene unit tests.

Comment: [M-x butterfly](http://xkcd.com/378/)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can corrupt stuff in any directory, just use the Directory api directly to mess up index files.

For example, take a look at the logic in Lucene's MockDirectoryWrapper.crash() (used in unit tests) to simulate a machine crash (by screwing up any not-yet-fsynced files): it simulates this by truncating the file, zeroing part of the file, deleting the file completely, or fully truncating the file to a 0 byte file.

http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/lucene/dev/trunk/lucene/test-framework/src/java/org/apache/lucene/store/MockDirectoryWrapper.java

Comment: Do you happen to have any links to a resource for setting up lucene unit tests? There doesn't seem to be a whole lot out there that I can find with Google.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming one of the index files is at least 2K:

```
dd if=/dev/urandom of=<index file> bs=1K count=1 seek=1K
```